# docker-compose vue+nginx with flask

Tags: docker, vue.js, nginx, flask, docker-compose

As title, I'm trying to dockerize my app(frontend: vue+ backend: flask), but have some problems with docker-compose(:docker newbie).

In order to serve the static files on nginx, I've copied them to: /usr/share/nginx/html,
but then I can't connect to my backend (flask api). I've checked the error which I highlighted in yellow(below image), it seems that frontend is not sending request to my flask api: http://localhost:5000/api, but sending to the static files location.

[image: error]

I've tried to revise Dockerfiles, docker-compose.yml, and none of these works.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

My project structures:

```
My project structure
   |___ backend
     |___ Dockerfile
     |___ app.py
   |___ frontend
     |___ Dockerfile
     |___ /app
     |___ /dist (static resource)
   |___ nginx
     |___ Dockerfile
   |___ docker-compose.yml
```

Below are my code:

**frontend Dockerfile**

```
# build vue image
FROM node:13.12.0-alpine3.11 AS build

# set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# g++ compiler for fibers and sass
RUN apk add python make g++

# install app dependencies
COPY ./app/package.json ./
COPY ./app/package-lock.json ./
#COPY ./app /app
RUN npm install
RUN npm install @vue/cli -g

# copy files
COPY . .

CMD npm run serve


# CREATE NGINX SERVER
FROM nginx:1.15.9-alpine AS prod-stage

COPY ./dist /usr/share/nginx/html

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

**backend Dockerfile**

```
# base image
FROM python:3.8-slim

# install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-transport-https && \
apt-get install -y libssl-dev libffi-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev build-essential \
libpq-dev netcat-openbsd

# set working directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# add and install requirements
COPY ./requirements.txt /usr/src/app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

#RUN python3 -m pip install -U pip
#RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

# add app
COPY . /usr/src/app

CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

---

**nginx.conf**

```
server {
    gzip on;
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;
    server_name  localhost;

location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files  $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
}

location ~ ^/api {
    proxy_pass http://backend:5000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_redirect    default;
    proxy_set_header  Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header  Connection "upgrade";
}
```

}

**nginx Dockerfile**

```
FROM nginx:1.15.9-alpine

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY . /etc/nginx/conf.d
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.7"


services:
# first container
   backend:
       # look for dockerfile and build the container
       build:
          context: ./backend
          dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
       restart: always
       # set environment variables
       environment:
          - APP_NAME=FlaskApp
       #  mount the volumes so we can change code and hot reload
       volumes:
          - './backend:/backend'
       #  expose port on the container, only to other containers
       expose:
          - 5000
       ports:
          - 5000:5000
       depends_on:
          -   frontend

nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    container_name:  nginx
    restart: always
    depends_on:
        - backend
        - frontend
    # port allows the host machine to link to container
    # pass 80 from host machine to 80 of the image filesystem
    ports:
        - "80:80"


frontend:
    build:
        context: ./frontend
        dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    volumes:
        - './frontend:/app'
        - '/app/node_modules'
    ports:
        - 8080:80
    environment:
        - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
        - NODE_ENV=development
        - BACKEND_SERVICE_URL=http://127.0.0.1:5000
        - VUE_GATEWAY_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8080
```